# How do the subplot indices work in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to make sense how the subplot indices work but they don't seem intuitive at all. I particularly have an issue with the third index. I know that there are other ways to create subplots in python but I am trying to understand how subplots written in such a manner work because they are used extensively.

I am trying to use a trivial example to see if I understand what I'm doing. So, here's what I want to do:

1. Row 1 has 3 columns
2. Row 2 has 2 columns
3. Row 3 has 3 columns
4. Rows 4 and 5 have 2 columns. However, I want to have the left subplot span rows 4 and 5.

This is the code for the first 3 rows. I don't understand why the third index of `ax4` is 3 instead of 4.

```python
ax1 = plt.subplot(5,3,1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(5,3,2)
ax3 = plt.subplot(5,3,3)

ax4 = plt.subplot(5,2,3)
ax5 = plt.subplot(5,2,4)

ax6 = plt.subplot(5,3,7)
ax7 = plt.subplot(5,3,8)
ax8 = plt.subplot(5,3,9)
```

For the three subplots that sit in rows 3 and 4, I can't seem to be able to do that. Here's my wrong attempt:

```python
ax9  = plt.subplot(4,2,10)
ax10 = plt.subplot(5,2,12)
ax11 = plt.subplot(5,2,15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indices are from left to right, and then wrap at the end of the row.  So `subplot(2, 3, x)`:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

For your example, `ax4=subplot(5, 3, x)` the subplots are indexed:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12 
13 14 15
```

For the `ax4=subplot(5, 2, x)` they are indexed:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

To span subplots, you can input the start and stop indices:

```py
ax9 = plt.subplot(5, 2, 7:9)
ax10 = plt.subplots(5, 2, 8:10)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: How does it not answer your question?

Comment: My question was not how to do it, but why is it done like that. You gave an example `subplot(2, 3, x)`. My question relates to how to choose `x`. From my original question, the `x` of `ax1`, `ax2`, and `ax3` are 1, 2, and 3. This makes perfect sense. Then for `ax4`, instead of `x` being 4, it is 3, why ? Then `ax6` goes back to 7 as if it is in order. I don't understand how `x` is chosen. That was my question. The example I gave is just to show that I don't really understand how to chose `x`.